# I include ajax based page in prime faces tab but it not work properly

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have included pages in prime faces tab. I have used id based form in each page. when I enable ajax for each page, then it is not working in the tab.

My prime-face index.xhtml page is below.

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="templet.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="top">
        <h1>Qubit Student Management System</h1>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">       
        <h:form id="menu">                
            <p:menubar autoDisplay="true">
                <p:submenu id="admin" label="Admin">
                    <p:submenu id="institute" label="Institute Setup">
                        <p:menuitem id="addInstitute" value="Add Info" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true"  update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="InstituteInformation"/>
                        </p:menuitem>

                        <p:menuitem id="viewInstitute" value="View Info" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true"  update=":outputForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="InstituteView"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="editInstitute" value="Edit Info" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true"  update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="InstituteEdit"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>


                    <p:submenu id="campus" label="Campus Setup">
                        <p:menuitem id="addCampus" value="Add Campus" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="CampusInformation"/>                                
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="viewCampus" value="View Campus" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="CampusList"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="editCampus" value="Edit Campus" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="CampusEdit"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>


                    <p:submenu id="department" label="Department Setup">
                        <p:menuitem id="addDepartment" value="Add Department" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="DepartmentInformation"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="viewDepartment" value="View Department" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="DepartmentList"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                        <p:menuitem id="editDepartment" value="Edit Department" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="DepartmentEdit"/>
                        </p:menuitem>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:submenu>

                <p:submenu id="student" label="Student">
                    <p:menuitem id="studentAdd" value="Student Add" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true"  update=":outputForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="StudentAdd"/>                                 
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem id="studentList" value="Student List" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="StudentList" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                    <p:menuitem id="studentAdmission" value="Student Admission" action="#{ajaxBean.editAction}" ajax="true" update=":outputForm">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ajaxBean.action}" value="StudentAdmission" />
                    </p:menuitem>
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form>       
        <h:form id="outputForm">
            <p:tabView id="outputTab">
                <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{ajaxBean.closeTab}"/>
                <c:forEach items="#{ajaxBean.chcekItem}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
                    <p:tab id="#{item}" title="#{item}" closable="true">                            
                        <ui:include src="#{bundle[item]}"/>   

                    </p:tab>
                </c:forEach>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form> 
        <a href="menuIteams.xhtml">Template</a>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="bottom">
        <h2 class="center">QubitLab Limited</h2>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

other some page below.

**institute/Create.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.InstituteInfo}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">

        <h:form id="institutesetupform">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_instituteCode}" for="instituteCode" />
                <h:inputText id="instituteCode" value="#{instituteController.selected.instituteCode}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_instituteCode}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateInstituteRequiredMessage_instituteCode}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_instituteName}" for="instituteName" />
                <h:inputText id="instituteName" value="#{instituteController.selected.instituteName}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_instituteName}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_location}" for="location" />
                <h:inputText id="location" value="#{instituteController.selected.location}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_location}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_phone}" for="phone" />
                <h:inputText id="phone" value="#{instituteController.selected.phone}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_phone}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_email}" for="email" />
                <h:inputText id="email" value="#{instituteController.selected.email}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_email}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_fax}" for="fax" />
                <h:inputText id="fax" value="#{instituteController.selected.fax}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_fax}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_web}" for="web" />
                <h:inputText id="web" value="#{instituteController.selected.web}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_web}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_about}" for="about" />
                <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="about" value="#{instituteController.selected.about}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_about}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_mission}" for="mission" />
                <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="mission" value="#{instituteController.selected.mission}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_mission}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_vision}" for="vision" />
                <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="vision" value="#{instituteController.selected.vision}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_vision}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteLabel_scop}" for="scop" />
                <h:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="30" id="scop" value="#{instituteController.selected.scop}" title="#{bundle.CreateInstituteTitle_scop}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <h:commandButton action="#{instituteController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateInstituteSaveLink}">
                <f:ajax execute="institutesetupform" render="institutesetupform:messagePanel"/>
            </h:commandButton>

            <br />

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**department/Create.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentTitle}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">

        <h:form id="departmentsetupform">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentLabel_departmentId}" for="departmentId" />
                <h:inputText id="departmentId" value="#{departmentController.selected.departmentId}" title="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentTitle_departmentId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentRequiredMessage_departmentId}"/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentLabel_departmentName}" for="departmentName" />
                <h:inputText id="departmentName" value="#{departmentController.selected.departmentName}" title="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentTitle_departmentName}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentLabel_history}" for="history" />
                <h:inputText id="history" value="#{departmentController.selected.history}" title="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentTitle_history}" />
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentLabel_program}" for="program" />
                <h:inputText id="program" value="#{departmentController.selected.program}" title="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentTitle_program}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <h:commandButton action="#{departmentController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentSaveLink}" >
                <f:ajax execute="departmentsetupform" render="departmentsetupform:messagePanel"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton action="#{departmentController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateDepartmentShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
        <br />

    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

when run every those page individually ajax can found form id but when i include those pages in **index.xhtml** page tab by clicking on **menu item** then it show

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'departmentsetupform' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt266
```

any one here help me for this regard..

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of referring to to the `departmentsetupform` form inside itself refer to `@form` and instead of `formname:messagePanel` refer directly to `messagePanel` like this

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="messagePanel"/>
```